# Quote newly created id in message box after SQL Insert in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a VBA script in MS Access that inserts a new record into a SQL Server table based on some inputs on the form.

```
Private Sub Allocate_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_ALLOCATIONS " _
    & "([Employee No],[Device Serial Number],[Start Date]) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.EmployeeNumber & "', '" & Me.SerialNumber & "', '" & Me.StartDate & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    Dim ReceiptNo As dao.Recordset
    Set ReceiptNo = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select @@identity")
    MsgBox "Device Successfully Allocated. Receipt ID is " & CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select @@identity")
End Sub
```

At the end, I query the ID that was auto-incremented during the insert. I want to then quote this in a Message Box so the user can make use of it elsewhere. How can I get it to quote like that in the MsgBox command? The one I have at the moment causes lots of issues around the fact I can't combine this command, and when using only 'ReceiptNo' it says it's not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should only ever be a single result in the recordset. Try changing your last line to:

```
MsgBox "Device Successfully Allocated. Receipt ID is " & ReceiptNo(0)
```

Comment: This works exactly as required. I had appended the ReceiptNo before, but hadn't added the column number selection which gave the result required

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to print an entire recordset. You need to refer to the column that you want to print and loop through the recordset while the end of file is not reached. Then output your column as string. I did not test it though.

```
While not ReceiptNo.EOF
    Msgbox Str(ReceiptNo!Identity)
    ReceiptNo.moveNext
Wend
```